# How do I monitor if SEO tags on my site changed during active development?

Tags: seo, monitoring

I work for a website that undergoes active development, with many production pushes per day. We are heavily SEO-dependent, and as our pages are being changed frequently by devs, we're always worried that an accidental change occurs to our page markup that negatively impacts SEO.

Are there tools out there that monitor this (changes to SEO-related markup), and notify you if a change occurs?

Answer (score 1):

I know two good German tools: [OnPage.org](http://de.onpage.org/) and [strucr.com](https://strucr.com/)

Both crawl your website regulary and show reports. OnPage.org is probably better for smaller sites, but have nicer reports. Strucr is good for big websites with many pages, but the reports are a IMHO bit more complicated.

Monitoring your SEO keywords in the SERPs only will show changes too late as Google sometimes takes really long to reflect changes.

Comment: Wasn't aware of those tools, thanks - I'll be checking them out.